# save multiple imagefiles to local

Tags: php, mysql

I have an affilate shop, and in my db are url's provided by the advertisers.
What i want to do is download all the images from their url's and save them to my local map.

I have in `products` `productImageUrl` an URL like http://www.------.nl/graphics/product_images/pTRUDE1-7034424dt.jpg

The best would be if i can insert the php code into a file that is used to perform the cronrefreshment

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

select all URLs you want to save and for each run this:

```
$image = file_get_contents($url);
file_put_contents("path/where/to/save/your_image_name.jpg", $image);
```